# OpenGLES can not use input argument in vertex shader in iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glsl

I'm new on OpenGLES, I want to draw an image. I have a problem when using an input float variable in my shader file. My sample code here

--- The drawing code

```
//Loading image texture with name "texName"
//........

//get index attribute and uniform

**//Get index of flag**
GLuint a_ver_flag_drawing_type = glGetAttribLocation(program[PROGRAM_POINT].id, "a_drawingType");

GLuint a_position_location = glGetAttribLocation(program[PROGRAM_POINT].id, "a_Position");
GLuint a_texture_coordinates_location = glGetAttribLocation(program[PROGRAM_POINT].id, "a_TextureCoordinates");
GLuint u_texture_unit_location = glGetUniformLocation(program[PROGRAM_POINT].id, "u_TextureUnit");

//Bind image texture with name "texName"
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texName);
glUniform1i(u_texture_unit_location, 0);

const float textrect[] = {-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId_1);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(textrect), textrect, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

**//Set value for flag**
glVertexAttrib1f(a_ver_flag_drawing_type, 1.0f);

glVertexAttribPointer(a_position_location, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT), (void*)(0));
glVertexAttribPointer(a_texture_coordinates_location, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT), (void*)(2 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT)));

glEnableVertexAttribArray(a_ver_flag_drawing_type);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(a_position_location);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(a_texture_coordinates_location);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

--- My vertex shader file

```
//Flag
attribute float a_drawingType;
varying highp float v_drawing_type;

//For drawing
attribute vec4 inVertex;

uniform mat4 MVP;
uniform float pointSize;
uniform lowp vec4 vertexColor;

varying lowp vec4 color;

//For texture
attribute vec4 a_Position;
attribute vec2 a_TextureCoordinates;

varying vec2 v_TextureCoordinates;

void main()
{
      v_drawing_type = a_drawingType;

//    if (fabs(a_drawingType - 1.0) < 0.00001) {
//        //Draw texture
           //v_TextureCoordinates = a_TextureCoordinates;
           //gl_Position = a_Position;
//    } else {
           //Draw some other stuff
//    }

    //Draw texture
    v_TextureCoordinates = a_TextureCoordinates;
    gl_Position = a_Position;
}
```

--- My fragment shader file

```
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D texture;
varying lowp vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D u_TextureUnit;
varying vec2 v_TextureCoordinates;

varying highp float v_drawing_type;

void main()
{
//    //Drawing point
//    gl_FragColor = color * texture2D(texture, gl_PointCoord);

    //Draw texture
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_TextureUnit, v_TextureCoordinates);
}
```

If just these code, I can draw my desired image. But if I uncomment the if statement code on vertex shader file

```
if (fabs(a_drawingType - 1.0) < 0.00001) {
      //Draw texture
     v_TextureCoordinates = a_TextureCoordinates;
     gl_Position = a_Position;
} else {
     //Draw some other stuff
}
```

the image is not rendered on screen anymore. I really don't know why it is. I want this flag to modify my drawing. If a_drawing_type is 1.0, I will draw image, else I will draw somethings else. I debug my drawing code and see if I uncomment this if statement, I can get indexes of these attribute at these lines

```
**//Get index of flag**
GLuint a_ver_flag_drawing_type = glGetAttribLocation(program[PROGRAM_POINT].id, "a_drawingType");

GLuint a_position_location = glGetAttribLocation(program[PROGRAM_POINT].id, "a_Position");
GLuint a_texture_coordinates_location = glGetAttribLocation(program[PROGRAM_POINT].id, "a_TextureCoordinates");
GLuint u_texture_unit_location = glGetUniformLocation(program[PROGRAM_POINT].id, "u_TextureUnit");
```

but if I comment the if statement, debug again and see that these indexes will have value 4294967295, I think it's max int value when it can't get the indexes.

Can anyone figure out for me what is the problem with if statement, I totally spent 2 days for this issue.

UPDATED:
I fixed above problem based on @Anonymous answer, but I have another issue related to it:
I want to pass the value of a_drawingType on vertex shader to the variable v_drawing_type in fragment shader, so the line of code

```
v_drawing_type = a_drawingType;
```

on vertex shader is right, isn't it? but now in fragment shader file, I add an if statement to check the value of the v_drawing_type

```
if (abs(v_drawing_type - 1.0) < 0.0001) {

}
```

it will also raise crash problem at line

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

Do I still miss somethings or I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, let's start from correcting sizeof().
There are plenty of places in your code using sizeof incorrectly:

```
sizeof(GL_FLOAT)
```

`GL_FLOAT` is `enum` (not `float`), you should rather use `sizeof(GLfloat)` or `sizeof(float)`
I belive it is fine on iOS, because `sizeof(int)` in fact is equal to `sizeof(float)`, however it is mistake.

Second, more importand thing is your `fabs()` call. First of all it should be `abs()` not fabs(). Also why there are 2 arguments? As far as I know `abs()` takes only 1 argument. I am pretty sure these things are reason of your headake, your shader cannot be compiled, so you don't get your image on screen.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I have mistake on abs argument, I want to write fabs(a_drawingType - 1.0) < 0.0001, let me update my question and try your suggestion

Comment: don't forget to change fabs to abs as well

Comment: Thanks @Anonymous, you're awesome, it works like a charm. I still have a problem, I will update my question, can you be willing help me again

Comment: If you have a different issue, post a different question.

Comment: Thanks @Anonymous, I fixed the problem myself, just because I have mistake in typing. Anyway thanks for your suggestion for the above problem, you really save me

Comment: Thanks @Rickster, my upcoming problem is still about this issue, it happens after I try this answer. But now I realized and fixed it myself

Comment: @Anonymous, I've updated my question with an issue after trying your answer, can you take a look and point me out

Comment: Please make a new post, narrow it to your current problem. Im using mobile terminal, its really hard to find anything in such monstrous post.